# How to replace a script tag with another in HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I would like to run a javascript code that replaces a certain string with another string, editing the page. I can do such easily with a string:

```
  var documentHTMLupdated = documentHTML.replace(originalString, newString);
```

but I need to have the html update. Calling `document.write()` again with the updated HTML does not work, as I don't want to have to reload the entire page (plus google chrome gets mad when I call `document.write()` ). **How can I update my HTML, only knowing the string I want to replace (no knowlede of element ID, etc), without calling document.write()?**

It would look something like:

```
<script> somefunction(); </script>
```

to

```
<script> updatedfunction(); </script>
```

Thank you for the help! (And my apologies if I asked this question poorly. I believe it fits community guidelines, but let me know if it doesn't so I can correct my mistakes)

Comment: What are you trying to replace? Is it just in the text content or are you wanting to replace actual markup too? Can you give an example?

Comment: it is unrealistic because it means to parser a whole html page whose structure is unknown

Comment: @Phil I'm trying to replace a script, so I suppose actual markup. It would look something like: `<script> somefunction(); </script>` to `<script> updatedfunction(); </script`

Comment: @WilkyRL write both functions in the script. and use whatever needed. This is not a good idea whatever you're planning to do!

Comment: What is the goal of this? Anything you execute via JavaScript to attempt to alter the document will happen **after** those scripts have already executed. That is, unless there's a lot more to this than you're presenting in your question

Comment: You can't override a script. However, it looks like the function you want to change, is global. You could override that function ..?

Comment: Interesting. Judging from comments it looks like what I want to do is not possible

Comment: Hope [this](https://jsfiddle.net/krxtvg1d/) simple demo might help you for replacing text and html separately.

Comment: @Phil I have a code injection system with features I am working on to replace blocks of HTML. Looks like  I need to find another solution.

Comment: @GauravMall Reading the question, there's bolded "_no knowlede of element ID, etc_" ...

Comment: @GauravMall thank you for the help, unfortunately your code doesn't quite fit my needs.

Comment: @WilkyRL Could you please explain in details what you actually need? Replacing the content of almost any other element is possible, but `script`. Or you can even replace the content of a _script element_, it just won't have any affect to the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instinctively I would loop on all text nodes and run a replace method on them. I'm not sure of the efficiency of this but on a small page it shouldn't be so heavy.
You can use `getElementsByTagName` to get all span, p, li.

Not very elegant but should work without having to reload the page.

Comment: I had the same thought at first but it seems OP wants to mess with the markup, not just text